# Invoke JNLP file from java code

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

is it possible to invoke .jnlp file from java code?

Example:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)
```

Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at [Desktop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class from Java ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you could just try

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javaws http://host:port/application_name/oyur_jnlp_filename.jnlp")
```

Try this out...

This will start a browser with your jnlp in it.

Comment: It's not **javaw** but **javaws**.

Answer (score 0):

The command line for running a jnlp would be `$JAVA_HOME/bin/javaws <jnlp file>`.